# R import txt file with read.table when there are apostrophes

Tags: r, txt, read.table

I have a txt file containing these values:

```
id,value
001,'Mary'
002,'Mary's husband'
```

When reading in R with read.table, you see there will be a bug with `'Mary's husband'` since there is an apostrophe.

How could we import the data in this case?

Comment: Try `df1$value <- gsub("^\\b'|'\\b$", "", df1$value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data in with `read.csv` as usual and then remove the apostrophes.

```r
txt <- "
id,value
001,'Mary'
002,'Mary's husband'"

df1 <- read.csv(textConnection(txt))
df1$value <- gsub("^'|'$", "", df1$value)
df1
#>   id          value
#> 1  1           Mary
#> 2  2 Mary's husband
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>